Etymology of the Hebrew word התגובות
What is the etymology of the Hebrew word התגובות?
Similar to "Word Power Made Easy by Norman Lewis", is there a similar book for Hebrew that explains etymology of various words?

Please note, I know that the meaning is "The comments". I am looking for etymology and not translation.

An etymological dictionary is a better resource than a particular writer's random selection of interesting words.
For example, Klein's Hebrew Etymology dictionary says that תְּגוּבָה
is a verbal noun formed from the Hiphil of גוב    "to answer, reply, to react", which  it says is "Borrowed from Aram. גוב (= to answer), which is related to Arab. ’ajāba (= he answered)"
